# Enable or disable button from one page to another page in htm flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

How to disable or enable button from different pages

I have two pages page1 & page2:

page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick=initialize() id="1" data-role="button" >Enable/Desable</button>

</body>
</html>
```

page2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>page2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick=initialize() id="2" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-corners="false" data-theme="b">Show My Position</button>
    <button onclick=calcRoute() id="3" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-corners="false" data-theme="b">Evacuate !</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to have the second button disabled by default, and have it enabled if clicking on the first page1 button. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

1.you can create a class for your button class="button disabled"and make css changes for that button class so button will be disabled.
2.use javascript window.onload function,while loading a page by using add event listener on onload function you can change enable/disable on your code.

Comment: How any sample code please share the example how its possible in html